# Expression Tree for .NET DateTime <> Oracle Timestamp like search

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oracle11g, expression-trees, odp.net-managed

I need to know whether I can get a clue or not.
 I am trying to build an Expression Tree that is evaluated via Entity Framework 6 (LINQ to Entities) via ODP.NET managed driver (current Version) to the appropriate Oracle statement in order to perform filtering. This works perfectly for string <> nvarchar2 datatypes. The output for a Contains search is something like:

```
Select * 
[...]
FROM "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" "Extent1"
WHERE ("Extent1"."ANVARCHAR2COLUM" LIKE '%givenStrValueToFind%')
```

Now I want to get the same result for a DateTime <> Timestamp(6) since this  line of sql statement is valid for an oracle query and returns all Dates which contains '08':

```
select * from "MYSCHEMA"."MYTABLE" where ATIMESTAMP6COLUMN like '%08%';
```

Since I am new to Expression Trees, I first need to know (after googling alot and tried this an that), whether this is possible before I dig deeper into. And if so, how could this be accomplished best? Since there is no Contains Method defined for DateTime and DateTime? Maybe providing Extension methods? And I dont want to execude queries directly against database.

Any hints would be nice to 'unhook' the given database datatype perhaps...
Thx.

Comment: Why do you need to build an expression tree and not use just LINQ Where?

Comment: Because I cannot hold all data in-memory. I already have had an in-memory solution working stripping diacritics an such things. But at this very moment I cannot say anything about the costs depending on reading all data from a table, converting it to a normal model (not DbSet Entity collecion) via select new{ x, y , z ...}. Plus I have then to cope with other things like when to invalidate single records which possibly are stale. So for now that was the simplest solution. Letting the DB doing the work. Except the DateTime string contains search.

Comment: Btw: the first in-memory solution was based in dynamic linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For EF 6 you can use :

```
ctx.MYTABLE.Where(x=>x.ATIMESTAMP6COLUMN.ToString().Contains("08")).ToList();
```

which translates to

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[some property name] AS [some property name], 
[Extent1].[ATIMESTAMP6COLUMN] AS [ATIMESTAMP6COLUMN], 
.
.
.
FROM [dbo].[MYTABLE] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  CAST( [Extent1].[ATIMESTAMP6COLUMN] AS nvarchar(max)) LIKE N'%08%'
```

As far as what I know all versions of EF does not support string functions but EF 6.x supports this kind of functions(The EF that I tested with is EF 6.1.3, the test is done with sql server localdb as DBMS).

Comment: Thx for your hint. I give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: Okay. It works. Plain only. Neither DbFuntions.AsNonUnicode() is wrapable around the date.toString() to avoid the CAST to NCLOB nor toString("g") is valid. I think I have to reconsider this and switch to date range filtering, since the Cast is unnecessary at all. And casting in where clauses... it´s dangerous ... Thx!

Comment: And yes.. I already knew this link.. but had forgotten it ^^ http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2327346-support-tostring-method-in-linq-to-entities

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood. Anyway, you don't need to build an expression tree to avoid DB load in memory. LINQ build an expression tree from an expression, EF translates the expression tree to a SQL statement (using the EF Provider) then the query is run on the DB.

In your case the LINQ Query should be something like this

```
myContext.MYTABLE.Where(e => e.ATIMESTAMP6COLUMN.Contains("08").ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Conversions:

You can use .ToString(). It should be a canonical function (function available on every EF Provider).

Other DateTime related functions:

You could have a look to other canonical functions (there are some about dates that allow to retrieve date parts) and also to non canonical functions (functions implemented only in EF Provider for oracle).

References:

Canonical functions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738626(v=vs.100).aspx

Actually I can't find non canonical functions for Oracle.
If you need it the best thing is that you ask another question.

Comment: Thx for your answer: How did you accomplish to get the Contains method on a DateTime Property? Maybe I am currently totally wrong, but intellisense isn´t providing it on my System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyEntityModel> for the particular DateTime property.

Comment: No, you are right. I edit the question with some solutions.

Comment: Thx. For your hint! I´ll check it.